# How to remove the border line around the element in html and css?

Tags: html, css

[the line around the blue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7Gq.jpg)

There is a line around the blue box. How can I remove it and just get the clean rounded box?
I have tried

```
{  
    border: none;  
    outline: none;  
}
```

but it doesn't work. I rounded the corners and then the line appeared which seems to be the outline when the corners are not rounded.

Here is my css and html code:

```css
body,html{
        height: 100%;
        color: #777;      
        line-height: 1.8;  
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;  
    }
    
       
    .bgimg{
        background-image: url(room1.jpg);
        min-height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.2;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;            
    }  

       .Sign-In{
           background-color: steelblue;
           color: black;
           opacity: 1;
           position:absolute;
           top:25%;
           left:37%;
           text-align: center;
           border-radius: 15px;
           font-family: cursive;
           width: 300px;
       }
       
       .marg{
           margin-top: 15px;
       }

       #button{         
           margin-bottom: 15px;
           padding: 10px;
           margin-top: 30px;  
           border-radius: 10px;         
       }

       .box{
           border-radius: 10px;
           width: 200px;
           text-align: center;
           border: none;
           height: 15px;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Sign-In</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2.css">  
   </head> 
  
  <body>
    <div class="bgimg">
    </div>
    <div class="Sign-In">
    <fieldset>
    <h2>LOG-IN</h2>
    <form method="POST" action=""> User <br>
    <input type="text" name="user" size="40" class="box">
    <div class="marg"> Password </div>
    <input type="password" name="pass" size="40" class="box"><br> 
    <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
    </form>
    </fieldset> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: Which element did you try removing the border from?

Comment: Its the Sign-In div element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the fieldset, it has a border by default.

```
fieldset {
    border: 0px;
}
```

You can read more about the styling of form / fieldset / etc elements [here](http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-fieldsetandlabels.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
fieldset {
  border: none;
}
```

```css
body,html{
 height: 100%;
 color: #777;      
 line-height: 1.8;  
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;  
}


.bgimg{
 background-image: url(room1.jpg);
 min-height: 100%;
 opacity: 0.2;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;            
}  

.Sign-In{
 background-color: steelblue;
 color: black;
 opacity: 1;
 position:absolute;
 top:25%;
 left:37%;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 15px;
 font-family: cursive;
 width: 300px;
}

.marg{
 margin-top: 15px;
}

#button{         
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;  
 border-radius: 10px;         
}

.box{
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 border: none;
 height: 15px;
}

fieldset {
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimg">
    </div>
    <div class="Sign-In">
    <fieldset>
    <h2>LOG-IN</h2>
    <form method="POST" action=""> User <br>
    <input type="text" name="user" size="40" class="box">
    <div class="marg"> Password </div>
    <input type="password" name="pass" size="40" class="box"><br> 
    <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
    </form>
    </fieldset> 
    </div>
```